# How can I see the size of each file in a particular directory in the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

When using the terminal, is there a command that allows you to see the size of each individual file in a particular directory?

Answer (score 3):

On Linux/Unix, use

- `ls -lk` (for size in kilobyte) or
- `ls -lh` (for easier readable approximate file sizes, like `12M` or `2G`).

`ls -l` will show size in *blocks*, which might not be that useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ls -l` to list all files with their details on OS X and Linux, or `dir` on Windows.

Comment: `man ls` would get you far but just to add to Darth's answer, adding `-h` will help you get a more human-readable output!

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party! `ls -lh` works if you don't want to know the size of directories *with their content* (all the directories just get listed as being 4 kilobytes).

Example output of `ls` command:

```
$ ls -lh
total 796K
drwxr-xr-x.  2 user user 4.0K Sep 25 20:04 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x.  7 user user 4.0K Aug 13 23:48 Documents
drwxr-xr-x.  6 user user 4.0K Nov 21 18:27 Downloads
drwx------. 12 user user 4.0K Nov 21 10:06 Dropbox
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user    5 Nov 21 22:06 file1
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user 751K Nov 21 22:06 file2
...
```

May I suggest `du -h -s /path/to/dir/*`
Example output of `du` command:

```
$ du -h -s *
4.0K    Desktop
980M    Documents
3.7G    Downloads
5.0G    Dropbox
4.0K    file1
752K    file2
...
```

Be ready to sit back and wait. Depending on how big the contents of the folder are and your IO speed, du can take quite a while.